# Geocoder - получаю ошибку grpc failed

Tags: kotlin

Получаю ошибку

> System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed at
>   android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)

при

```
val geoCoder = Geocoder(localActivity, ruLocale)
val addressesText = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
            p1.latitude,
            p1.longitude,
            1
)
currentAddress.text = addressesText.first().getAddressLine(0)
```

не понимаю в чем дело =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, на смартфоне не было интернета, со включенным интернет всё ок.